# Using multiple databases with DooPHP

Tags: php, database, frameworks, doophp

I'm checking out DooPHP and I can't seem to find how to use multiple database connections simultaneously. I just want to have multiple database objects and use their methods to query the DB. Now I I'm doing this:

```
Doo::db()->setDb($dbconfig, $config['APP_MODE']);
Doo::db()->query('.......');
```

and then setDb again when I want to use another DB. This is retarded though. It's very difficult to find what you're looking for in the API documentation as well.

Any help here?

Comment: have you tried to specific the database name into the sql ? assuming all database are in the same host, listening on same port, same user has equally privileges on both databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to do this in index.php:

```
Doo::loadCore('db/DooSqlMagic');
$db = new DooSqlMagic;
$db->setDb($dbconfig, 'db'.$config['APP_MODE']);
$db->connect();

$db2 = new DooSqlMagic;
$db2->setDb($dbconfig, 'db2'.$config['APP_MODE']);
$db2->connect();
```

This in db.conf.php:

```
$dbconfig['dbdev'] = array('localhost', 'db', 'root', '', 'mysql', true, 'collate'=>'utf8_unicode_ci', 'charset'=>'utf8');
$dbconfig['dbprod'] = array('localhost', 'db', 'root', '', 'mysql', true, 'collate'=>'utf8_unicode_ci', 'charset'=>'utf8');

$dbconfig['db2dev'] = array('localhost', 'db2', 'root', '', 'mysql', true, 'collate'=>'utf8_unicode_ci', 'charset'=>'utf8');
$dbconfig['db2prod'] = array('localhost', 'db2', 'root', '', 'mysql', true, 'collate'=>'utf8_unicode_ci', 'charset'=>'utf8');
```

And use it like this in the controller:

```
global $db;
global $db2;
$db->query('.......');
$db2->query('......');
```